# Angular: How can I wait for a promise in a service to be resolved before I set the returned value in my controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, promise

I'm using angular and have the following service:

```
myApp.factory('MyService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        getData: function (ID) {
            var promise = $http.get('Holdings/GetGridData?Id=' + ID)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
            return promise;
   }};
}]);
```

and then I call that in my controller using:

```
function createData(ID) {
    MyService.getData(ID).then(function (data) {
        $scope.JsonData = data;
    });

    return $scope.JsonData;
};
```

However, when CreateData is first fired it returns undefined, and after this is returned, I can see in the console I can see it display: XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:50243/Holdings/GetGridData?Id=2".

So, it correctly reads the data, but after my $scope.JsonData is set to undefined. After this, when I fire the event again, $scope.JsonData is correctly set to the data, however. My question is, on the first time the event is fired, how can I make the controller wait for the promise in the service to be resolved before setting the value?

Comment: Is it the controller of route? If so, what router do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't possible. Why don't you like the promise approach in controller?

First call of the function will return undefined. Meanwhile, promise is resolved, value is set on the scope and this triggers $digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the response.data before the promise for one, and you're not actually returning the http request itself from the service.

Also, you don't need to return anything in your controller.  The simplest way to accomplish this is just returning your $http request from the service and handling the response in your controller.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/bmopcr97/

```
function AppCtrl($scope, Service) {
  var ID = 123;
  Service.getData(ID).then(function(response) {
    $scope.JsonData = response.data;
  });
}

function Service($http) {
  return {
    getData: function(ID) {
      return $http.get('Holdings/GetGridData?Id=' + ID);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A great way to handle this is through your router's resolvers. Here's an example of using a resolver in angular's default router (it's a little different if you use ui-router, but the concept is the same).

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl: "newsView.html",
        controller: "newsController",
        resolve: {
            message: function(messageService){
                return messageService.getMessage();
        }
    }
});
```

Here, `messageService.getMessage()` returns a promise (similar to your example function `getData()`). If you then include `message` as an argument in your controller, the controller will wait for the promise to be resolved before executing.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to defer, resolve and return your promises in a 'Factory' or 'Services' file. 
Then make a call to the respective method in the Factory file in your 'Controller' file. 
Factories and Controllers perform totally different functions. All your API calls will
have to be your 'Factory' file and then you can manipulate your data in your 
'Controller'

Refer to example below :

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# user.factory.js
# 'app.foo.user' refers to your directory structure i.e. app/foo/user/user.factory.js

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.foo.user', [])
        .factory('userSvc', UserService);

    /* @ngInject */
    function UserService(
        $log,
        $q,
        $http,
        $window,
        $state,
        logger,
        session,
        utils,
        API_CONFIG) {

        var ENDPOINTS = {
            USERS: '/v1/users'
        };

        /**
         * @ngdoc service
         * @name app.foo.user
         * @description User management
         */
        var service = {
            get: get
        };

        /**
         * @ngdoc method
         * @name get
         * @description Returns all users
         * @methodOf app.foo.user
         * @returms {promise} user or null if not found
         */
        function get() {
            var q = $q.defer();

            var request = utils.buildAuthRequest( session, 'GET', ENDPOINTS.USERS );

            $http(request)
              .success(function (users) {
                  q.resolve(users.result);
              })
              .error(function (error) {
                  logger.error('UserService.get > Error ', error);

            return q.promise;
        }
    }
})();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# user.module.js
# 'app.foo.user' refers to your directory structure i.e. app/foo/user/user.module.js

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.foo.user', [
        ]);
})();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# user-list.controller.js
# This is where you make a call to the 'get' method in the 'user.factory.js' where the promises 
# were defered, resolved and returned.
# And you gave to inject 'userSvc' in this file so as to connect to the 'user.factory.js' file.
# 'app.foo.admin' refers to your directory structure i.e. app/foo/admin/user-list.controller.js

 (function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.foo.admin')
        .controller('UsersListController', UsersListController);

    /* @ngInject */

    function UsersListController(
        $scope,
        $state,
        $timeout,
        $log,
        userSvc) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.loading = false;
        vm.userSvc = userSvc;

        activate();

        function activate() {
            // init users
            vm.userSvc.get().then(
                function(users) {
                    vm.users = users;
                },
                function(error) {
                    $log.error(error);
                }
            );
        }
    }
})();
```